# Remote debugging of C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, remote-debugging, autocad

MS Visual Studio 2013; C++.

I have the installed MS VS 2005-2015 on my local machine. My other remote machine has the installed AutoCAD 2009-2016. I always (many years) use the remote debugging when I write my .net plugins for AutoCADs. It is very convenient and works fine. Therefore I want to use remote debugging for ARX plugins too.

I created a "Hello World" ARX project for AutoCAD 2009 through the MS VS 2013 with V80 [MSVS 2005] tools using (AutoCAD 2009 requires to compile C++ plugins [ARX] through Visual Studio 2005).

I compiled it and run in AutoCAD 2009 sucessfully.

But I can't launch the remote debugging. Attached files display my project settings and the message with a problem.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand which RDBG (2005 or 2013) I am to launch on the remote machine... I tried to use both, and also with\without the admin rights, but it didn't help me.

How can I get successfull remote debugging of ARX?

Comment: Same user on both machines? Firewall down?

Comment: I can't switch off the firewall for the domain network, for admin rights even. I haven't rights for it. Why I have not the problem for remote debugging my .Net applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason of my problem. When I used the remote debugging for my .net applications, I didn't point the working directory and it worked fine. But for C++ projects I am to point it. If I set the working directory as `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2009\` then the remote debugging works fine with C++ code too.